# Code First with MySQL does not create tables

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, .net-core

Trying to create a code first project using Entity Framework and MySQL.
When I use `context.Database.EnsureCreated();` the tables are created correctly, but I would like to use migrations so the code changes to: `context.Database.Migrate();` and that is when I get the error:

> MySqlException: Table 'library.publishers' doesn't exist

I do see that the database was created and there is an empty table: `__efmigrationshistory` but that is the only table, no publishers like it does with the EnsureCreated.

What Am I missing here?

Here is the minimal code reproducing the error:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace mySqlEFcore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new LibraryContext())
            {
                context.Database.Migrate();
                context.Publishers.Add(new Publisher { ID = 1 });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        private class Publisher
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
        }

        private class LibraryContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Publisher> Publishers { get; set; }

            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=library;user=root;password=123456;SslMode=none;");
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Publisher>(entity => { entity.HasKey(e => e.ID); });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried running `Add-Migration InitialCreate` but ran into more errors ... 
Added a reference `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` and now the InitialCreate shows:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommandBuilderFactory..ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.IDiagnosticsLogger'1, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalTypeMapper)'.
>      at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLCommandBuilderFactory..ctor(IDiagnosticsLogger'1 logger, IRelationalTypeMapper typeMapper)

Comment: Was told that by the EF team that this is an issue with the Oracle MySQL package, they recommended to use `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` instead, that works fine!

Comment: Just wrestling with the same problem but with the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql provider. Were you able to make any progress in this regards?

Comment: @MichaelKargl No issues with the Pomelo package, here is my project: https://github.com/heldersepu/csharp-proj/tree/PreDocDB/mySqlEFcore

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately still the same "table does not exist" spiel. May I ask what version of mysql and dotnet core you are using? Maybe I have a version incompatibility to tackle.

Comment: @MichaelKargl Yes it's OK to get the "table does not exist" the first time, that is pointing you to run the `Add-Migration InitialCreate` that should create everything... take a look on my project for the versions

Comment: Got it to work by creating a new "InitialMigrationToMysql" summarizing the previous ones. After that, the tables got generated nicely. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The comment from @Helder Sepulveda solved my issue.
The steps that I followed:

1. Open **Package Manager Console**.
2. `Enable-Migrations`
3. `Add-Migration InitialCreate`   (*or whatever name that you wish.*)
4. `Update-Database`

The tables were then created in my MySQL database.